# No post, No Display, Strange behavior

Tags: memory, power-supply, freeze, troubleshooting, post

I have a relatively new computer. While I was working, it started to show strange white flashes (the flash doesn't cover the entire screen and is in the form of randomly spaced bars sometimes) when I switch between users. It wouldn't go away without restarting. After a while (maybe an hour or two) it froze entirely and when I restarted it, it entered a boot/restart loop that happens before it reaches POST.

The only way for this loop not to happen is by inserting only one RAM, but then it would just turn on normally only to display nothing, not even POST and the mouse and keyboard are not responsive, even when I tried a completely new RAM. When I start it without RAM it beeps just fine to indicate the absence of RAM.

Any idea what is going on?

http://pcpartpicker.com/list/8rbrr7

Answer (score 0):

If you installed new RAM and you still get no POST, the RAM wont be the problem. To make sure that the Motherboard is still ok, de-attach all other parts such as HDD, GPU (if you have onboard) and all the RAM except one. If you restart now and get no POST, Beeb-codes and you are 100% sure that your RAM is ok, then you need to replace the mainboard.